# AS3 remove multiple children of a sprite object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a button in an app that users can click to add multiple input fields. The function is below.

```
private var fieldHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();

private function addInviteFriend(event:starling.events.Event):void
{
    this.newFriendInvite = new TextInput();
    this.newFriendInvite.backgroundSkin = new Quad(Constants.STAGE_WIDTH - 80, 30, 0xd0d0d1);
    this.newFriendInvite.width = Constants.STAGE_WIDTH - 110;
    this.newFriendInvite.height = 30;
    this.newFriendInvite.text = "";
    this.fieldHolder.addChild(this.newFriendInvite);
    this.newFriendInvite.x = 0;
    this.newFriendInvite.y = this.fieldHolder.height;

    this.removeInvitedFriend = new Button();
    this.removeInvitedFriend.defaultSkin = new Image(Assets.getAtlasTexture("btn-delete"));
    this.fieldHolder.addChild(this.removeInvitedFriend);
    this.removeInvitedFriend.x = int((this.newFriendInvite.x + this.newFriendInvite.width) - this.newFriendInvite.defaultSkin.width);
    this.removeInvitedFriend.y = int(this.newFriendInvite.y);
    this.removeInvitedFriend.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.TRIGGERED, removeInviteFriendClick);

    this.addInviteFriendButton.y = this.fieldHolder.y + this.fieldHolder.height + 30 + 1;
}

private function removeInviteFriendClick(event:starling.events.Event):void
{
    var child:Sprite = event.currentTarget as Sprite;       
    this.fieldHolder.removeChild(child);
}
```

Everything works great, I can add multiple input fields however the problem is that when I click the remove button only the button itself is removed and not the textinput field. I know why only the button is being removed but I don't know how to include the textinput in the removeChild process.

I tried creating another Sprite to hold all the instances of fieldHolder but that didn't work. I also tried removeChildren but that didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you call `this.fiedHolder.removeChildren();` in `removeInviteFriendClick` the children don't get removed?

Comment: It removes all input and remove buttons not just the 'group' that was clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the two elements into a container and then call `removeChildren` on that?

```
private var fieldHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();

private function addInviteFriend(event:starling.events.Event):void
{
    var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

    this.newFriendInvite = new TextInput();
    this.newFriendInvite.backgroundSkin = new Quad(Constants.STAGE_WIDTH - 80, 30, 0xd0d0d1);
    this.newFriendInvite.width = Constants.STAGE_WIDTH - 110;
    this.newFriendInvite.height = 30;
    this.newFriendInvite.text = "";
    this.newFriendInvite.x = 0;
    this.newFriendInvite.y = this.fieldHolder.height;
    container.addChild(this.newFriendInvite);

    this.removeInvitedFriend = new Button();
    this.removeInvitedFriend.defaultSkin = new Image(Assets.getAtlasTexture("btn-delete"));
    this.removeInvitedFriend.x = int((this.newFriendInvite.x + this.newFriendInvite.width) - this.newFriendInvite.defaultSkin.width);
    this.removeInvitedFriend.y = int(this.newFriendInvite.y);
    this.removeInvitedFriend.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.TRIGGERED, removeInviteFriendClick);
    container.addChild(this.removeInvitedFriend);

    this.addInviteFriendButton.y = this.fieldHolder.y + this.fieldHolder.height + 30 + 1;

    this.fieldHolder.addChild(container);
}

private function removeInviteFriendClick(event:starling.events.Event):void
{
    var child:Sprite = event.currentTarget as Sprite;       
    child.parent.removeChildren();
}
```